# Checking answer to conditional probability and general probability question

Tags: probability

A  machine  has  10  parts.   It  is  housed  in  a  low-budget  data  center,  that  has  just experienced a hurricane.  The hurricane will cause each part in the machine to fail independently of all other parts of the machine with probability p. Also:

- If no parts of the machine fail, it never crashes.
- If exactly one of the parts in the machine fails, it will crash on 40% of     inputs.
- If more than one part in the machine fails, it will crash on all inputs.

a) What is the probability that no parts of the machine fail?  (Your answer should be in terms of p).
Answer: $ (1-p)^{10}$

b) What is the probability that exactly one part of the machine fails?  (Your answer should be in terms of p).
Answer: $ {10 \choose 1} p^1(1-p)^{10}$

c) Since you are not allowed to check the internals of the machine, you instead feed the machine 7 independent random inputs. Amazingly, the machine never crashes! What is the probability that none of the machine's parts have failed?  (Your answer should be in terms of p.)

Answer: Let A be the event that none of the parts have failed. Let E be the event that the machine hasn't crashed over 7 inputs.

$ Pr(A | E) = \frac{A \cap E}{Pr(E)}$ The $Pr(A \cap E) = 1$, because if the none of the parts have failed then the machine cannot have crashed.

$Pr(E) = Pr(E|A)Pr(A) + Pr(E|-A)Pr(-A) = 1*p + 0$

So the answer is $\frac{1}{p}$

d) Now suppose that you want to decide whether or not exactly one part of the machine has failed. Here is the test you will use.  You will feed the machine $n$ independent random inputs.  If the machine (a) crashes on at least one input, and (b) doesn't crash on at least one other input,you conclude that exactly one part of the machine has failed. Suppose exactly one part of the machine has failed. How big should $n$ be to ensure that your test arrives at the correct conclusion with probability at least 80%?  (Your answer should be a number.)

Answer: I approached this problem by defining A as the event that the Machine Crashes on at least one input, and B as the event that the machine doesn't crash on an input. $Pr(A \cap B) = 6/25$, so solve $n*6/25 > .8$, and n is 10/3, or rounded to 4 inputs necessary.

Comment: Answer to question 2 should be $\binom{1}{10}p^1(1-p)^{10}$. The union is composed of not incompatible events. The process is of binomial form.

Comment: My mistake, I see that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in (b) - the answer is $10p(1-p)^9$. Also, your answer for (c) is incorrect. Let $A,B$ and $C$ be the respective events that no parts fail, one part fails and more than one part fails. Let $E$ be the event that the machine does not crash over 7 random, independent inputs. We have
$$P(A|E)=\frac{P(A\cap E)}{P(E)}$$
as you wrote. However, $P(A\cap E)=P(A)=(1-p)^{10}$, not $1$ as you wrote (if $A$ occurs then $E$ must occur, so $A\cap E=A$). To calculate $P(E)$ we need to break it up into disjoint events, namely
$$P(E)=P(A\cap E)+P(B\cap E)+P(C\cap E).$$
We already calculate $P(A\cap E)=(1-p)^{10}$. Clearly $C\cap E=\emptyset$, so $P(C\cap E)=0$. Finally, we compute
$$P(B\cap E)=P(B)P(E|B)=10p(1-p)^9\cdot(\tfrac35)^7$$
where the second equality follows from the fact that if exactly one part fails, each input independently has a $3/5$ chance of not crashing, and thus $P(E|B)=(\frac35)^7$. Simplify to get your final answer. You can do a similar thing for (d), replacing $7$ with $n$ and finding the smallest such $n$ that $P(A|E)>0.8$.